# How can you correlate logs with APM?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest, querydsl, apm

I have an application that will write logs to elasticsearch using serilog. I configured the APM server using docker-compose. Once I start the application up and perform an operation (navigate through pages in the browser), then close the application. Those logs are then recorded to elasticsearch. I came across this [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-easily-correlate-logs-apm-traces-for-better-observability-elastic-stack) that talks about correlating logs with APM. I selected a few steps to follow since I am not using python in this application, and noticed that there are transactions that are inside of APM.

**With these transactions, how I would I be able to correlate the logs to each other. In other words, how can I tie these logs together is there a unique variable/id/key that will tie all the logs that were recorded in one single transaction (when I started the application, performed operations, then closed the application)?**

When I looked into each of the transactions, I noticed that they have a transcation_id and a trace_id. But, they are changing per each operation that I am performing. **I am wanting to know if it is possible and if it is, how can I gather all the logs that pertain to that single transaction?** For instance, if I query by a single id, then all of those logs will be returned.

[image]

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:7.13.0
    depends_on:
      elasticsearch:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy
    cap_add: ["CHOWN", "DAC_OVERRIDE", "SETGID", "SETUID"]
    cap_drop: ["ALL"]
    ports:
    - 8200:8200
    networks:
    - elastic
    command: >
       apm-server -e
         -E apm-server.rum.enabled=true
         -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601
         -E setup.template.settings.index.number_of_replicas=0
         -E apm-server.kibana.enabled=true
         -E apm-server.kibana.host=kibana:5601
         -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 12
      test: curl --write-out 'HTTP %{http_code}' --fail --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8200/

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.0
    environment:
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    - cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-XX:UseAVX=2 -Xms1g -Xmx1g
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        hard: -1
        soft: -1
    volumes:
    - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
    - 9200:9200
    networks:
    - elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 20s
      retries: 10
      test: curl -s http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health | grep -vq '"status":"red"'

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.13.0
    depends_on:
      elasticsearch:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
    - 5601:5601
    networks:
    - elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 20
      test: curl --write-out 'HTTP %{http_code}' --fail --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:5601/api/status

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

---

**UPDATED**

After looking into the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/serilog.html) for `Elastic.Apm.SerilogEnricher`, I went ahead and included it to my `Startup.cs` file and my `Program.cs` file. Just wanted to double check that I am incorporating it correctly.

`Startup.cs`:

```
namespace CustomerSimulatorApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{ElasticApmTraceId} {ElasticApmTransactionId} {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // create a new node instance
            var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            // settings instance for the node
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
            settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

            services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(new ElasticClient(settings));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAllElasticApm(Configuration);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
namespace CustomerSimulatorApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }


        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
                        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                        .WriteTo.Console()
                        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(context.Configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"]))
                        {
                            IndexFormat = $"{context.Configuration["ApplicationName"]}-logs-{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
                            AutoRegisterTemplate = true
                        })
                        .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseAllElasticApm();
    }
}
```

I noticed when I ran the program and performed operations on the browser then checking APM that the trace.id & transaction.id are still changing so I am not able to correlate this single transaction that I performed on the browser with the logs. Did I implement the `Elastic.Apm.SerilogEnricher` incorrectly above?

[image]

Different ID's (there are more diff. ones but do not want to expand it with screenshots)

[image]

They all change per page redirect so I am unable to gather the logs from a single ID.

This is what I see on the console as well with the updated startup.cs and program.cs files:

[image]

I eventually shut down the program:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Serilog to send logs to Elasticsearch, and also using Elastic APM .NET agent in your application to capture traces, you can reference [`Elastic.Apm.SerilogEnricher`](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/v1.5.0/src/Elastic.Apm.SerilogEnricher) to enrich logs with APM trace ids and transaction ids (and in a coming 1.6 release, span ids) if there is an active transaction when logging

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
   .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{ElasticApmTraceId} {ElasticApmTransactionId} {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}")
   .CreateLogger();
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/serilog.html), which has more information.

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and read the documentation. Can you please review my updated post where I am including the implementation for this just to verify that I did it correctly please?

Comment: I ran the application with the way I have it set in program.cs and startup.cs and I am still getting the id's to change throughout. Did I implement it incorrectly?

Comment: @NoviceCoder The example logs to console output with the provided template, it's intentionally simple. What you probably want to do is use  `Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog` and `Elastic.Apm.SerilogEnricher` to log events in ECS format using `EcsTextFormatter`, and include APM data with .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo(). See https://github.com/elastic/ecs-dotnet/tree/master/src/Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog

Comment: I appreciate it, will look into this!